# multiple setState/states conflicting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple conflicting states causing my navigation items to show and then disappear after scrolling. I had my scroll event working perfectly until I tried checking for smaller devices. It seems that the state defined in `checkWidth` is causing the nav items to show.

**Is there a better way to handle multiple states in this case?** So they only fire when they should. Any help is appreciated.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isTop: true,
  };
}
```

```
onScroll(isTop) {
  this.setState({ isTop });
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.updateWindowDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
  document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const isTop = window.scrollY < window.innerHeight - 50;
    if (isTop !== this.state.isTop) {
      this.onScroll(isTop);
    }
  });

  this.checkWidth = () => {
    const match = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: 768px)`);
    if (match) {
      this.setState({isTop: false});
    }
  };

  this.checkWidth();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.checkWidth);
}
```

Comment: `So they only fire when they should` what should fire and when it should fire? Please explain that

Comment: What I mean by that is the nav items should be hidden until I scroll to the `window.innerHeight` I set and they should show on devices smaller than `768px`. Now they show initially, then disappear, and everything functions fine after

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

   With this tool for example, if you call the function listened in the scroll event multiple times in 0.3s, it is executed only once after you stop scrolling:

   `var efficientScroll = debounce(function() {...}, 250);`
2. Why the `resize` event is listened with two different functions. It is neccesary? Maybe you can improve that too. And apply debounce too.

Answer (score 0):

On a mobile device, method `checkWidth()` sets `isTop` to false, even when it *is* at the top. That could get confusing.

I think it would make more sense to control the visibility of the nav menu based on two state properties: `isTop` and `isNarrowWidth`.

OR: you could change `isTop` to `navMenuVisible` and calculate this state property based on both the values of `window.scrollY` and  `window.matchMedia()`. This basically combines `checkWidth()` and your onScroll callback into a single method.

---

(And I would move all this logic from the `document.addEventListener` callback to `onScroll()`. Not necessary, but it makes sense to put all the things that happen on a scroll inside this method.)